# Как программно задать ссылки в тексте TextView?

Tags: android, textview

Я собираю Activity программно, без использования разметки .xml
Среди прочего есть и несколько TextView, примерно такого вида:

```
final TextView tvDesc = new TextView(this);
    tvDesc.setText("Описание тут! http://тут_какой-то_адрес.com/about.php а дальше ещё какой-то текст и ещё какие-то ссылки");
    tvDesc.setTextSize(14);
    tvDesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, какой текст туда упадёт, но знаю, что там могут быть ссылки на вэб-страницы. И эти ссылки надо сделать активными (кликабельными). В xml разметке там всё просто:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="@+id/tvDescription"/>
```

В разметке `android:autoLink="web" android:linksClickable="true"`всё решают, но как добиться этого в файле JAVA?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Извините за беспокойство! Пока формулировал вопрос - сам в нём разобрался :)
Сделал так:

```
    final TextView tvDesc = new TextView(this);
    tvDesc.setText("Описание тут! http://тут_какой-то_адрес.com/about.php а дальше ещё какой-то текст и ещё какие-то ссылки");
    tvDesc.setTextSize(14);
    tvDesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tvDesc.setAutoLinkMask(webViewStyle);
```

Всем спасибо.